# Get acces token in salesforce

Tags: community, single-sign-on

I have an hybrid app (1 part using Salesforce and another one using Java Spring boot).

I'm making login on Salesforce by SSO but after login, I need to get the access token for the user and use it to make api calls towards my Java app.

I have no idea how I can get the access token in Salesforce...Can someone help me with that?

Thank you so much in advance.
Regards

Comment: You are using sso then you can use SAML Oauth2 flow.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_sso_flow.htm&type=5

Comment: I have configured the Salesforce SAML but I need to get it after the make login with SSO in Salesforce.

I'm using this function `Auth.AuthToken.getAccessToken` in a Salesforce Apex class (after make login inside in) but I'm getting a null all the time...

Do you know if this function works to get the token?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/hybrid_managing_sessions.htm